# Supervisor custom path for logs

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord

I use supervisor for Laravel Queue workers. Here is my main conf:

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)
chown=root:supervisor

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/www/SITENAME.COM/storage/logs/supervisor.log            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

.
. 
.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

And this is my custom conf for laravel worker

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=sudo php /var/www/SITENAME.COM/artisan queue:work --sleep=5 --tries=2 --daemon
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/SITENAME.COM/storage/logs/queues.outputs.log
stderr_logfile=/var/www/SITENAME.COM/storage/logs/queues.errors.log
```

Here are my log files and their permission.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data    0 Dec 28 19:47 queues.errors.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data    0 Dec 28 19:47 queues.outputs.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data    0 Jan  2 12:34 supervisor.log
```

**The problem is the supervisor works very well but logs are not submitted at all.**

Comment: Please include your supervisor code parts

Comment: what do you mean? it's already in the description.